# Attempt to insert non-property list object - NSUserDefaults - Class Property

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, nsuserdefaults

I know that they've been already lot of questions about this issue but mine is kind of different.

What I want to do is to save a "class property" in NSUserDefaults. To create the "class property" I did this:

```
// MyClass.h

   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   static NSString *userIndex;

   @interface PlanGenerator : NSObject

   + (void)setUserIndex:(NSString *)userIndexNew;
   + (NSString *)userIndex;

   @end


// MyClass.m

   #import "MyClass.h"
   @implementation MyClass

   + (void)setUserIndex:(NSString *)userIndexNew
   {    
      userIndex = userIndexNew;

      NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];    
      [userDefaults setObject:userDefaults forKey:@"UserIndex"];
      [userDefaults synchronize];
   }

   + (NSString *)userIndex
   {
      return userIndex;
   }

   @end
```

But when I want to setObject: userIndex the app crashes with the error:

```
attempt to insert non-property list object <NSUserDefaults: 0x109409e50> for key UserIndex'
```

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like "userIndex = userJahrgNeu;" ? Also, it seems that you're trying to do "UserDefaultsception", is that intentional?

Comment: I am very sorry for this confusion. That's because i edited code from a real project and tried to use general variable names. I fixed it and now it should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems somewhat confusing as the exception claims to be using key `UserJahrg` and not `UserIndex`, however the issue is that you are attempting to add `userDefaults` to itself:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];    
[userDefaults setObject:userDefaults forKey:@"UserIndex"];
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You probably meant `userIndex`:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];    
[userDefaults setObject:userIndex forKey:@"UserIndex"];
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. What a shame I did see that. And again, sorry for the confusion with the variable names.

Comment: I mean I didn't see it